# How to parse properly?

Tags: android, html, parsing, url, scrape

Hi I am trying to parse the facebook reels from website.
The link is this https://www.facebook.com/reel/837433680652559?mibextid=9drbnH&s=yWDuG2&fs=e

The problem is that the video and audio have different source urls and needs to be combined. (which is fine).

The only thing I am doing is extracting all possible video and audio urls available on this page. Since there are data of 3-4 urls on this page, its hard to identify which audio url fits in which video url.

Can anybody help please?